# Highcharts xaxis datetime issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js to plot 3 graphs in one and the xaxis data is dynamically picked using the pointStart function such that 14 dates come up on the xaxis (14 days in my backend data)

But, when I pick data at an hourly level, in total 14 * 24 data points show up on the xaxis in the form of dates and it's extremely cluttered and 14*24 dates is being shown on xaxis.

I only want the same representation as I had in the daily data which was 14 dates, even though there are 14 * 24 bars for the metric value that is being shown in the chart.

Even in the hourly format, I only want 14 days to show up in the xaxis.

The current code is as follows within the series part :

```
    pointStart:Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getDate()),
tickInterval : 24 * 3600 * 1000 ,
pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
```

And this is the result of that code :

http://tinypic.com/r/2s0ba4k/8

But at an hourly level, 14*24 bars will come up and each will have an xaxis label.
But I want only 14 labels.

I have tried :

## 1

```
labels : {
    step : 24
    }
```

But this doesn't work as now, it displays 14-15 dates but they are spread across all the bars ie first date is 28 apr , then next date is 22 may and keeps adding 24 dates to all.

But I want first date 28 apr, 2nd date 29th apr and so on.

I wanted to know more approaches to solve this problem.
All suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different range between bars (e.g. 1hour or 1day) then you should change the same way `pointInterval` value. So:

- one day: `pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000`
- one hour: `pointInterval: 3600 * 1000`

It's interval between two points, so you need to tell Highcharts what is the proper one, if you set always to 1day, then Highcharts will set 1day.

Comment: My problem is that my data is changing by a drop down menu, once it is daily data which is plotted perfectly with the first command.
But, when data becomes hourly via drop down, the interval is shown in dates and I get many dates in the xaxis. 

So i have to use functions within pointInterval or probably some version of series update function.
Can you suggest any approach along the same lines

Comment: You can't use function within `pointInterval`, but you can simply update that option in real time: `chart.series[index].update({ pointInterval: new_value })`.